# Erlang/OTP ElixirLS version conflict

Tags: elixir

According to chatGPT ElixirLS version 0.17.10 is not compatible with Erlang/OTP 25.3.2.7 which is the package used to compile Elixir 1.15.7 with.  Does anyone out there know what ElixirLS version closest to 0.17.10 is compatible with Erlang/OTP 25.3.2.7.  I am receiving errors regarding the ElixirLS Server crashing 5 times and then aborting.  I am hoping this incompatibility issue is the culprit.
In the name of completeness here is what I am seeing (5 times prior to aborting)

```
Installing ElixirLS release v0.17.10
Running in c:/Users/Gordon/servy/lib/servy
Install complete
[Info  - 5:32:40 PM] Started ElixirLS v0.17.10
[Info  - 5:32:40 PM] Running in c:/Users/Gordon/servy/lib/servy
[Info  - 5:32:40 PM] ElixirLS built with elixir "1.15.7" on OTP "25"
[Info  - 5:32:40 PM] Running on elixir "1.15.7 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)" on OTP "25"
[Info  - 5:32:40 PM] Protocols are not consolidated
[Info  - 5:32:40 PM] Elixir sources not found (checking in c:/home/runner/work/elixir/elixir).           Code navigation to Elixir modules disabled.
[Info  - 5:32:40 PM] Received client configuration via workspace/configuration
%{"additionalWatchedExtensions" => [], "autoBuild" => true, "autoInsertRequiredAlias" => true,      "dialyzerEnabled" => true, "dialyzerFormat" => "dialyxir_long", "dialyzerWarnOpts" => [], "enableTestLenses" => false, "envVariables" => %{}, "fetchDeps" => false, "languageServerOverridePath" => "", "mixEnv" => "test", "mixTarget" => "", "projectDir" => "C:\\Users\\Gordon\\servy", "signatureAfterComplete" => true, "suggestSpecs" => true, "trace" => %  {"server" => "off"}}
```

[Error - 5:32:40 PM] Project directory c:/Users/Gordon/servy/lib/servy/Users/Gordon/servy does not exist
[Info  - 5:32:42 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
true

The Project directory is actually c:/Users/Gordon/serv - somehow lib/servy/Users/Gordon/servy was added?

The launch.json file
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "Elixir Debug",
"type": "mix_task",
"request": "launch",
"task": "run",
"internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
"projectDir": "c:\Users\Gordon\servy"
}
]
}

Changing launch.json file and settings.json file with regards elixirLS project directory - unsuccessful.

Uninstalling ElixirLS and reinstalling - unsuccessful.

Comment: For future reference we don't usually put a signature in a question. :) I've taken the liberty of removing the signature from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1.) Check this chart [Supported Elixir And OTP Versions for Elixir LS](https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls#supported-elixir-and-otp-versions)

2.) Try compiling Elixir LS from source and see if that works.